# How can I create a table with images that adjust to fit the size of the <td> box?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a mobile version of a spa website for a friend, and I have been able to get the images to fit to the screen size properly, but there is always room left over in each table cell that I want the image to utilize instead of wasting space. 
 Here is the relevant HTML/CSS I'm using:

```
<table class="wide">
<tr>
<td><img class="service-4-pics" src="pic.jpg"/></td>
<td><img class="service-4-pics" src="pic.jpg"/></td>
<td><img class="service-4-pics" src="pic.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

table.wide {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
display: block;}

img.service-4-pics {
margin: auto;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also should set the width of the `<td>` cells:

CSS:

```
table.wide td {
    width: 33%;
}
```

OR, HTML:

```
<table class="wide">
<tr>
<td width="33%"><img class="service-4-pics" src="pic.jpg"/></td>
<td width="34%"><img class="service-4-pics" src="pic.jpg"/></td>
<td width="33%"><img class="service-4-pics" src="pic.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I tried that out but it wouldn't work :/ The images will utilize most of the space in each cell only when the browser view is very large. When I shrink the browser the images takes up less and less space in the cell as the browser shrinks. Not sure why it's doing this :<